# rollback transaction in microservice(grpc)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-transactions, grpc-java

I have two microservices called grpcLogin and grpcCityPlace.

Which are related to grps and  each other having separate datasource.

From microservis grpcLogin  I call microservis grpcCityPlace.

I want the Microservis grpcCityPlace operation to be rolled back if an error occurs in Microservice grpcLogin .

How can I perform the rollback operation on the microservice grpcCityPlace  by the microservice grpcLogin  with the spring boot and grpc?

I also want rollback in delete and update operations.

grpcLogin:

```
  public AdminUserModel create(@NotNull AdminUserModel adminUserModel) throws UtilityException, IllegalAccessException, BusinessException, InvocationTargetException {

    //create Admin
    AdminUser adminUser = new AdminUser();
    adminUser.setFirstName(adminUserModel.getFirstName());
    adminUser.setLastName(adminUserModel.getLastName());
    adminUser.setPassword(PasswordEncoderGenerator.generate(adminUserModel.getPassword()));
    adminUser.setUsername(adminUserModel.getUsername());
    adminUser.setDateOfBirth(CalendarTools.getDateFromCustomDate(adminUserModel.getDateOfBirth()));
    adminUser.setGender(etcItemService.findByIdAndCheckEntity(adminUserModel.getGender_id(), GenderEnum.class,null,true));

    adminUser = adminUserRepository.save(adminUser);

    //add cityPlace For Admin
    CreateRequestModel createRequestModel =  CreateRequestModel.newBuilder()
            .setAdminUserId(adminUser.getId())
            .setCityId(cityReadOneResponse.getId())
            .setLatitude("35.791354")
            .setLongitude("51.356406")
            .setTitle("OfficePlace")
            .build();
    //call grpcCreate
    final CreateResponseModel createResponseModel= this.cityPlaceStub.grpcCreate(createRequestModel);

    //It's just written to express what I mean.
    if(true){
       throw new Exception();
    } 

    adminUserModel.setId(adminUser.getId());
    return adminUserModel;
}
```

grpcCityPlace:

```
@Override
public void grpcCreate(CreateRequestModel createRequestModel, StreamObserver<CreateResponseModel> responseObserver) {
    CreateResponseModel.Builder createResponseModel = CreateResponseModel.newBuilder();
    CityPlaceModel cityPlaceModel = new CityPlaceModel();
    cityPlaceModel.setCity_id(createRequestModel.getCityId());
    cityPlaceModel.setLatitude(createRequestModel.getLatitude());
    cityPlaceModel.setLongitude(createRequestModel.getLongitude());
    cityPlaceModel.setAdminUserId(createRequestModel.getAdminUserId());
    cityPlaceModel.setTitle(createRequestModel.getTitle());

    CityPlace cityPlace = new CityPlace();

    cityPlace.setAdminUserId(cityPlaceModel.getAdminUserId());
    City city = cityRepository.findById(cityPlaceModel.getCity_id()).get();
    cityPlace.setCity(city);
    cityPlace.setLatitude(cityPlaceModel.getLatitude());
    cityPlace.setLongitude(cityPlaceModel.getLongitude());
    cityPlace.setTitle(cityPlaceModel.getTitle());
    cityPlace = cityPlaceRepository.save(cityPlace);

    cityPlaceModel = this.create(cityPlaceModel);

    responseObserver.onNext(createResponseModel.build());
    responseObserver.onCompleted();
}
```

Comment: If you are talking about real microservices isolated from each other having separate datasource then you can not rollback transactions. But maybe you can do some compansation by sending a message/reqeust to the other service. But for that you may need to have some sort of event logs in your grpcCityService so that you can trace the previous action and revert it. Or using some orchestrator with saga pattern as in defined here https://blog.couchbase.com/saga-pattern-implement-business-transactions-using-microservices-part/

Comment: Another option: think to merge these services into a single one. Highly likely you have split them incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [saga pattern](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html) to with compensating transaction which will rollback previous transaction.

Or you can have 2 phase commit algorithm implemented with Transaction Coordinator and Transaction managers.